# Setting data in correct JSON format using Array and Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

Below is the model for which I have to set the data. I am using array and dictionary to achieve this, Here is the code which I tried. But its giving me the output which is `invalid JSON`.
One more thing I want to ask is why the `log of an array starts and ends with small braces?`
Any help would be much appreciated.

**Code:**

```
NSDictionary *paramDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       parameterName,@"parameterName",
                       parameterType, @"parameterType",
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:parameterSorting],@"parameterSorting",[NSNumber numberWithBool:parameterSorting],
                       @"parameterOrdering",
                       nil];

NSMutableArray *paramArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:paramDic];
NSDictionary *paramData = @{@"rqBody":@{@"catalogName":@"",@"userId":@"", @"parameter":paramArray, @"catalogMode":@""}};

NSData *postData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:paramData];`
```

**Output:**

```
{"rqBody":{"catalogName":"abcd","userId":"65265hgshg76","parameter":"(
        {
        parameterName = anandShankar;
        parameterOrdering = 1;
        parameterSorting = 1;
        parameterType = Text;
    }
)","catalogMode":"xxxxxx"}}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
{"rqBody":{"catalogName":"abcd","userId":"65265hgshg76","parameter":[{
        "parameterName" : "anandShankar",
        "parameterOrdering" : 1,
        "parameterSorting" : 1,
        "parameterType" : "Text"
    }],"catalogMode":"xxxxxx"}}
```

Comment: "parameter":[{  show array of dictionary so can you just put dictionary to array and set to paramData dictionary...

Comment: Its paramDic, I am adding this as object into the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
NSDictionary *paramDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Object1",@"parameterName",
        @"Object2", @"parameterType",
        @'Object3',@"parameterSorting",@"Object4",
        @"parameterOrdering",
                nil];
NSMutableArray *paramArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:paramDic];

NSDictionary *paramData = @{@"rqBody":@{@"catalogName":@"",@"userId":@"", @"parameter":paramArray, @"catalogMode":@""}};
```

Add this lines :

```
NSError * err;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:paramData options:0 error:&err];
NSString * myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", myString); // it will print valid json
```

**JSON**

```
{  
  "rqBody":{  
     "catalogName":"",
     "parameter":[  
        {  
           "parameterOrdering":"Object4",
           "parameterName":"Object1",
           "parameterType":"Object2",
           "parameterSorting":51
        }
     ],
     "userId":"",
     "catalogMode":""
  }
}
```

Comment: Array is my requirement, But still I tried and the above code doesn't produce valid JSON As well :(

Comment: Check my update I've tested it and it will produce valid JSON

Comment: Check update it will create a valid JSON with an NSArray inside

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in it. in console or log round braces `()` indicates array. if it is showing round braces then it is array. you will never het `[]` square braces in console or log.

Update :

```
  NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:paramData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

and then send this data to server. it will in your desired json fromat

hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how would I replace these semiColumn with comma,So that my data would be valid json?

Comment: would you like to send this data in server ?

Comment: :Yes, Please check the required format in question.

Comment: check my update in answer. you need to convert in data like this and you can send this data to server by using `nsurlsession`

Comment: don't use NSKeyedArchiver, use `nsjsonserialization` as i mentioned in answer. pass your final dictonary and send that data to server